# Using GridSplitter in a Xaml file for both Silverlight and WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml, gridsplitter

I have a Xaml file which is used in a project which can be built for both Silverlight and WPF.    I want to use the GridSplitter control.  However, this control is in different Xaml namespaces on Silverlight and desktop WPF.

In WPF, the namespace is: `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation`
On Silverlight, it is: `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk`

So if the xaml code is `<GridSplitter/>`, it will work on WPF but not Silverlight, and if the code is `<sdk:GridSplitter/>`, it will work on Silverlight but not WPF.

Is there a way to write this so that it works on both platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to create my own class that derived from GridSplitter.

```
public class MyGridSplitter : GridSplitter { }
```

Then I put an xmlns for my project at the top of my xaml file:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:mynamespace"
```

And then I could just use the local namespace prefix for my GridSplitter:

```
<local:MyGridSplitter />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, in your wpf use this namespace:
**xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"**
Then the tag is the same. You would just have to change the x:sdk tag to move from wpf to silverlight and back.

Comment: OK, but how do I use a different value for xmnls:sdk between wpf and Silverlight?  I want the same Xaml code to work on both.

Comment: it would be the same xaml code except for that one line, there's not way that I know of to not change any lines.